# Query databases that have MYISAM tables that do not have only fulltext index tables

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, information-schema

I am trying to query from the `information_schema` where the database (`table_schema`) has `MYISAM` tables but does not have only `fulltext index` tables.

The `statistics` tables is very poorly designed for the query that I need. If you look, the `table_schema and table_name` appear multiple times.  Thus querying `where table_name != 'fulltext'` is not an option because there could be another row in `statistics` table for that table that is `Btree` which usually the case for `PK indexes` on tables. This results in that table that has a `fulltext` coming back using the above mentioned where clause in query.

So with that being said here is my Query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (a.TABLE_SCHEMA)
FROM
    information_schema. TABLES a
INNER JOIN information_schema.statistics b ON a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME,
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.TABLE_SCHEMA,c.table_name
    FROM
        information_schema.statistics c
    WHERE
        c.index_type = 'FULLTEXT'

) AS fullTextTables
WHERE
    a. ENGINE = 'MyISAM'
AND a.table_schema NOT IN (
    'information_schema',
    'mysql',
    'performance_schema'
)
AND (a.Table_schema != fullTextTables.Table_schema AND b.table_name != fullTextTables.table_name);
```

The problem is that when I run this I am still getting back databases that only have 1 or 2 tables left in them that have not been converted from `MYISAM`; those tables still have `Fulltext indexes`. The `Mysql` version is `5.5` and not `5.6`. Note: upgrading at this point is not an option.

Any help amending this query to get proper results would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `OR` instead of `AND` for the last line.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick but same result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM tables with FULLTEXT index and other index(es).

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    FROM  information_schema.statistics AS s1
    JOIN  information_schema.statistics AS s2  USING (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
    JOIN  information_schema.TABLES AS t       USING (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE  s1.index_type = 'FULLTEXT'
      AND  s2.index_type != 'FULLTEXT'
      AND  t.ENGINE = 'MyISAM'
      AND  TABLE_SCHEMA  NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');
```

# MyISAM tables with no FT index:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    FROM  information_schema.TABLES AS t
    WHERE  t.ENGINE = 'MyISAM'
      AND  TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql',
                'performance_schema'
                          )
      AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  information_schema.statistics
            WHERE  index_type = 'FULLTEXT'
              AND  TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
              AND  TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
      );
```

# MyISAM tables, counting index_types:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,
        SUM(index_type = 'FULLTEXT') AS FT_indexes,
        SUM(index_type != 'FULLTEXT') AS others
    FROM  information_schema.TABLES AS t
    JOIN  information_schema.statistics USING(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE  t.ENGINE = 'MyISAM'
      AND  TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql',
                'performance_schema'
                          )
    GROUP BY  1,2;
```

Tack on a `HAVING FT_indexes = 0` to get just those with no FT index.

Etc.

Comment: SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,
        SUM(index_type = 'FULLTEXT') AS FT_indexes,
        SUM(index_type != 'FULLTEXT') AS others
    FROM  information_schema.TABLES AS t
    JOIN  information_schema.statistics USING(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE  t.ENGINE = 'MyISAM'
      AND  TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql',
                'performance_schema'
                          )
    GROUP BY  1,2  **HAVING FT_indexes = 0**;

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` is a shortcut for `GROUP BY whatever-the-first-field-in-SELECT-is`.  In this case `TABLE_SCHEMA`.  (etc)